# Неполный тип. Перекрестные классы

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

Добрый вечер. Мне нужно из класса `B` получать доступ к методам класса `A`. Имеется вот такой код:

```
#include <vector>

class B;
class A
{
public:
    std::vector<B*> _b;
    void setup()
    {
        for (auto it = _b.begin(); it != _b.end(); it++)
        {
            (*it)->setPtr(this);
        }
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    A *_a = nullptr;
    void setPtr(A *a) { *_a = *a; }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
}
```

Компилятор выдает ошибки:

```
error C2027: использование неопределенного типа "B"
error C2227: выражение слева от "->setPtr" должно указывать на тип класса, структуры или объединения либо на универсальный тип
```

Как с таким бороться, если менять классы местами нельзя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вынесите реализацию метода отдельно, после объявлений классов.

```
#include <vector>

class B;
class A
{
public:
    std::vector<B*> _b;
    void setup();
};

class B
{
public:
    A *_a = nullptr;
    void setPtr(A *a) { *_a = *a; }
};

void A::setup()
{
    for (auto it = _b.begin(); it != _b.end(); it++)
    {
        (*it)->setPtr(this);
    }
}


int main()
{
    A a;
}
```

Comment: помогло. Но тогда такой вопрос, как быть в случае если классы и реализации раскиданы по различным файлам. Как правильно организовать подключение `#includ-ов`?

Comment: @Nikita. L: Это сильно меняет смысл вопроса.

Comment: Реализации обычно - в .cpp-файлах (или inline в include'ах), объявления - в заголовочных. Но это - обычно, могут быть и исключения. Давайте лучше будет конкретный вопрос, в общем случае могут быть только вот такие нечеткие рекомендации, и не более того...

Comment: "Не вижу препятствий" (с) Директор тюрьмы :)

Comment: @Harry, я задал заново вопрос ибо слишком много кода. [link](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/779505/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: А я только что постарался ответить :)