# Неполный тип. Перекрестные классы. Проблема заголовков

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

Есть 2 класса реализации и объявления которых раскиданы по файлам. Я пытаюсь из класса `Elements` обратиться к полю `_gameInt` но ничего не выходит. Файлы выглядят так:

`Game.h`:

```
#include <vector>
class Game
{
...
public:
int _gameInt;
void setup();
std::vector<Elements*> _elements;
...
}
```

`Game.cpp`:

```
#include "Game.h"
...
void Game::setup()
{
...
for (auto it =  _elements.begin(); it != _elements.end(); it++) (*it)->setGamePtr(this);
...
}
```

`Elements.h`:

```
class Elements
{
...
friend class Game;
Game *_thisGame;
void setGamePtr(Game *game);
void foo();
...
}
```

`Elements.cpp`:

```
#include "Elements.h"
...
void Elements::setGamePtr(Game *game)
{
_thisGame = game;
}
...
void Elements::foo()
{
...
(*_thisGame)->_gameInt = 5; //тут ругается компилятор
...
}
```

В функции `foo()` в выделенной строке компилятор ругается:

```
недопустимый неполный тип
требуется имя члена
```

Я правильно понимаю что это из-за того что `#includ-ы` неправильно подключаются?
Как с таким бороться?

Comment: Если у вас используется какой-то тип в заголовочном файле, который вы после подключаете в файл который использует этот тип, вы получите циклическую ошибку. Объявите прототип класса в заголовке, а в файле реализации подключите требуемый заголовок, таким образом вы избавитесь от зацикливания, и сохраните чистоту кода.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы внес оба объявления столь тесно взаимосвязанных классов в один заголовочный файл - все равно один класс без другого не имеет смысла! Точно так же и всю реализацию бы вынес в один .cpp-файл.

Но если уж так нужно разные - то в ваших заголовочных файлах я бы добавил перед определениями классов предварительные объявления других - `Elements` перед `Game` и наоборот, а в реализациях включал бы оба заголовочных файла.

Но еще раз - в принципе не вижу ни малейшего смысла в разнесении столь связанных классов по разным файлам.

Comment: в который раз помогаете, спасибо. Тут сразу вопрос возникает. А когда вообще следует раскидывать классы по отдельным файлам? В данном случае мои классы имели еще и наследников. Стоило их всех тоже помещать в один заголовочный файл? Или только родители в одном классе а наследники в разных? Это все очень не очевидно.

Comment: @Harry, а лучше все инкапсулировать в один класс (как считаете?)

Comment: @Nikita. L, не совсем сложно определяться в тривиальных проектах.  Создавая проект вы сначала старайтесь  задать цель. Если ваша цель заключается в решении одной задачи или нескольких схожих , тесно связанных, то ограничивайтесь одним файлом.  Ну в принципе чтоб на ваш вопрос ответить  по моему придется написать целую главу книги, если не больше...

Comment: Вообще-то, если вы планируете использовать что-то потом повторно - то вынесение имеет смысл (как и вынесение в очень большом проекте - чтобы не компилировать постоянно все, а только необходимое), а если ни то и ни другое - то просто особого смысла нет. Главное - должно быть так, чтобы вам было удобно :)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Не уверен, большой класс - это зачастую тоже не лучшее решение.

Comment: @Harry,  я наверное не совсем четко выразился, но отметил, что речь  идет о тривиальных задачах. В любом случаи  вы правы - зачастую, но не всегда ведь.  P. S.  мне всегда приятно  получать ваш ответ...

Answer (score 5):

В такой ситуации вам надо принять волевое решение о том, какой тип (и, соответственно, заголовок) считать более низкоуровневым, а какой - более высокоуровневым. При включении заголовочных файлов, разрешается включать только более низкоуровневые заголовки в более высокоуровневые заголовки, но не наоборот. При необходимости упомянуть в низкоуровневом заголовке тип из более высокоуровневого заголовка просто делается предварительное объявление типа.

Например, в вашем случае естественно было бы считать тип `Elements` и заголовок `Elements.h` более низкоукровневым, а тип `Game` и заголовок `Game.h` - более высокоуровневым.

В такой ситуации в заголовочном файле `Elements.h` мы делаем предварительное объявление класса `Game`, но `Game.h` в `Elements.h` ни в коем случае не включаем

```
// Elements.h
#ifndef ELEMENTS_H_
#define ELEMENTS_H_

class Game; // Предварительное объявление высокоуровневого типа

class Elements
{
...
friend class Game;
Game *_thisGame;
void setGamePtr(Game *game);
void foo();
...
};

#endif /* ELEMENTS_H_ */
```

А заголовочный файл `Game.h` реализуем "обычным" образом, т.е. ни о чем не беспокоясь включаем в него `Elements.h`

```
// Game.h
#ifndef GAME_H_
#define GAME_H_

#include <vector>
#include "Elements.h"

class Game
{
...
public:
int _gameInt;
void setup();
std::vector<Elements*> _elements;
...
};

#endif /* GAME_H_ */
```

Далее, в файл реализации `Elements.cpp` спокойно включаем все, что нам нужно, т.е. и `Elements.h`, и `Game.h`

```
// Elements.cpp
#include "Elements.h"
#include "Game.h"
...
void Elements::setGamePtr(Game *game)
{
_thisGame = game;
}
...
void Elements::foo()
{
...
(*_thisGame)->_gameInt = 5;
...
}
```

А в `Game.cpp` достаточно включить `Game.h` (но ничего страшного не случится, если вы включите и `Elements.h` тоже)

```
// Game.cpp
#include "Game.h"
...
void Game::setup()
{
...
for (auto it =  _elements.begin(); it != _elements.end(); it++) (*it)->setGamePtr(this);
...
}
```

Вот и все.

При этом у вас есть полная свобода в реализации класса `Game` - вы можете реализовывать его методы где угодно, в т.ч. в `Game.h`, т.е. можете обойтись без `Game.cpp` вообще. Также вы можете содержать в классе `Game` подобъекты класса `Element`, то есть напрямую, а не через указатель.

А вот с классом `Elements` у вас будут ограничения - полным типом тип `Game` будет являться только в `Elements.cpp` и все методы, требующие полноты типа `Game` придется реализовывать именно там. То есть класс `Elements` может содержать только непрямые ссылки (указатели) на класс `Game`.

При таком разбиении вы не можете реализовывать методы `Elements`, работающие с `Game`, как inline функции. Но при необходимости и это достижимо заведением дополнительного включаемого файла.